# How can I execute a VBScript file from Ant script?

Tags: ant, vbscript

I want to run a VBScript file from an Ant script. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task. It allows you to execute a system command from your Ant script.

EDIT: 
An example could be:

```
<target name="RunVbScript">
    <exec executable="cscript">
        <arg value="MyScript.vbs"/>
        <arg value="argument 1" />
        <arg value="argument 2" />
        <arg value="argument n" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: yeah you are right but...using "exec" i can call batch file....and in batch file i can call vbscript,but i want to call directly vbscript from ant script...could i do that?

Comment: The exec task can be used to execute any command. Please see my edits.